# Underscore JS templates best practice - how to avoid mixing JavaScript with HTML

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I would like to know if there is a good method to avoid mixing JavaScript with HTML in a BackboneJS/UnderscoreJS templates application.

My understanding is that we need to create template code, which looks more or less like that:

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1' >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <% _.each(items,function(item,key,list){ %>
        <% var f = item.name; %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= key %></td>
                <td class="<%= f %>"><%= item.name %></td>
            </tr>
        <% }); %> <!-- this is hardly readable -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That, what bothers me is a necessity to write JavaScript, inside <% %> scriptlet, then some HTML, then again some JavaScript, a loop or if/else condition has to be closed elsewhere inside <% %>.

Such code resembles me a lot early days of JSP pages (JavaServer Pages) - even scriptlets use the same notation - and I remember that such approach often caused maintenance and debugging problems. Here I had similar problems - scriptlet is transformed by template engine into actual JavaScript, which is not easy to analyze.

Is there any way to handle templates better? Even though I try to do as much filtering, data preparation in the backend, some typicaly frontend logic is always needed (like highlighting something, etc.)?

Comment: Different template systems provide different capabilities. In doT.js for example, there's an iteration facility that's reminiscent of `<c:forEach>` in JSP JSTL/EL. Underscore templates seem to be *very* simple.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to really avoid mixing the <% tags with html. There are quite a few templating alternatives, but they all use placeholders of some sort. (Mustache is quite readable) The loops and conditions can to handled in views to some extent - e.g. BackboneMarionette has Collection and Composite views to deal with loops, but you can't really avoid them as it is the core of the template.

You could try to use plain HTML and post-process it with a xpath to insert content, but my guess is that you would just end up with more confusion.

Comment: I think that it depends on how much logic your sticking into the template, if it's getting messy then perhaps you should split it into two, for example you can use a *innerTemplate* and loop over your collection rendering each item with that template (I'm not sure on what the performance difference will be though, but you should be able to minimize it a bit by precompiling the templates).

Comment: Go here and pick out the features you want: http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/